# Polymorphic nested form results in AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

#### Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role, :polymorphic => true

class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :role

class Dealer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :role

class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :role
```

---

#### Dealer controller:

```
  def new
    @dealer = Dealer.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml  { render :xml => @dealer }
    end
  end

  def create
    @dealer = Dealer.new(params[:dealer])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @dealer.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Dealer was successfully created.'
        format.html { redirect_to [:admin, @dealer] }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @dealer, :status => :created, :location => @dealer }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @dealer.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

---

#### Error message:

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Admin/dealersController#create
>   User(#41048900) expected, got HashWithIndifferentAccess(#23699520)

#### Request Parameters:

```
{"authenticity_token"=>"+GkeOOxVi1Fxl7ccbV0Ctt5R6shyMlF+3UWgRow2RdI=",
 "dealer"=>{"gender"=>"m",
 "forename"=>"",
 "surname"=>"",
 "company"=>"",
 "address1"=>"",
 "address2"=>"",
 "zipcode"=>"",
 "city"=>"",
 "country"=>"1",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"",
 "password"=>""},
 "phone"=>"",
 "mobile"=>"",
 "fax"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

I guess my problem is that Rails doesn't convert the "user" hash inside the request hash into a User object — but why and how can I make Rails to do that?

Comment: what kind of view code do you have with this man?  i guess i could piece it together from your hash but that is no good. plus you forgot your accepts_nested_attributes_for i'm sure somewhere too.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution for this? I'm getting the same problem, been trying all sorts of concoctions to get it working, but alas...

Answer (score 8):

Just spent several hours on this including bumping into this thread.  Finally found on another forum:
the attribute setter expects to get your params in this form

```
{ ...,
  "user_attributes" => {"email" => "", "password" => ""},
  ... }
```

NOT

```
{ ...,
  "user" => {"email" => "", "password" => ""},
  ... }
```

In order to get this, your view should look something like this:

```
form_for @dealer do |f|
 ...
 f.fields_for :user, @dealer.user do |u|
   ...
 end
 ...
end
```

This works for me on Rails 3.0.3

Comment: I did this in Rails 3.2.5 but it doesn;t work, I got same error and the form of accept params is still "user" => not "user_attributes" =>, so any help pleasE?